# phpMailer, Error: data not accepted

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

Estoy tratando de enviar un correos a través de un formulario `html` con `php`, el código que uso es el siguiente:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

    try {
        //Server settings
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                                       // Enable verbose debug output
        $mail->isSMTP();                                            // Set mailer to use SMTP
        $mail->Host       = 'smtp.office365.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
        $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication

        $mail->Username   = 'correo@domio.com';                     // SMTP username
        $mail->Password   = 'passwordCorreo';                               // SMTP password
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                                  // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
        $mail->Port       = 587;

        //Recipients
        $mail->setFrom($from, $username);
        $mail->addAddress($address, 'Contacto');     // Add a recipient

        // Content
        $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
        $mail->Subject = $subject;
        $mail->Body    = "<b>".$body."</b>";

        $mail->send();
        echo 'Message has been sent';
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
    }
```

Por lo que he visto en varios foros y publicaciones mi código no esta mal ya que es el mismo que proporciona `PHPMAILER` para las conexiones, lo único que cambié son los parámetros de conexión a mi servidor de correo.

El error que me genera es el siguiente:

```
2019-07-05 16:00:52 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 PR2PR09CA0009.outlook.office365.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Fri, 5 Jul 2019 16:00:51 +0000
2019-07-05 16:00:52 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost
2019-07-05 16:00:53 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-PR2PR09CA0009.outlook.office365.com Hello [200.77.121.178]250-SIZE 157286400250-PIPELINING250-DSN250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-STARTTLS250-8BITMIME250-BINARYMIME250-CHUNKING250 SMTPUTF8
2019-07-05 16:00:53 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
2019-07-05 16:00:53 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 SMTP server ready
2019-07-05 16:00:54 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost
2019-07-05 16:00:54 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-PR2PR09CA0009.outlook.office365.com Hello [200.77.121.178]250-SIZE 157286400250-PIPELINING250-DSN250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-AUTH LOGIN XOAUTH2250-8BITMIME250-BINARYMIME250-CHUNKING250 SMTPUTF8
2019-07-05 16:00:54 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN
2019-07-05 16:00:54 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
2019-07-05 16:00:54 CLIENT -> SERVER: <credentials hidden>
2019-07-05 16:00:54 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
2019-07-05 16:00:54 CLIENT -> SERVER: <credentials hidden>
2019-07-05 16:00:58 SERVER -> CLIENT: 235 2.7.0 Authentication successful
2019-07-05 16:00:58 CLIENT -> SERVER: MAIL FROM:<selarbac.angel@hotmail.com>
2019-07-05 16:00:58 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 2.1.0 Sender OK
2019-07-05 16:00:58 CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO:<comercializacion_vikingo@hergarza.com.mx>
2019-07-05 16:00:58 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 2.1.5 Recipient OK
2019-07-05 16:00:58 CLIENT -> SERVER: DATA
2019-07-05 16:00:58 SERVER -> CLIENT: 354 Start mail input; end with <CRLF>.<CRLF>
2019-07-05 16:00:58 CLIENT -> SERVER: Date: Fri, 5 Jul 2019 18:00:52 +0200
2019-07-05 16:00:58 CLIENT -> SERVER: To: Contacto <correo@dominio.com>
2019-07-05 16:00:58 CLIENT -> SERVER: From: angel <Correo@ejemplo.com>
2019-07-05 16:00:58 CLIENT -> SERVER: Subject: prueba
2019-07-05 16:00:58 CLIENT -> SERVER: Message-ID: <qnIg2OM4a9NZSGR25nPDtj8wHauwwjRZqHGVgZbV0M@localhost>
2019-07-05 16:00:58 CLIENT -> SERVER: X-Mailer: PHPMailer 6.0.7 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)
2019-07-05 16:00:58 CLIENT -> SERVER: MIME-Version: 1.0
2019-07-05 16:00:58 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
2019-07-05 16:00:58 CLIENT -> SERVER: 
2019-07-05 16:00:58 CLIENT -> SERVER: <b>prueba mensaje</b>
2019-07-05 16:00:58 CLIENT -> SERVER: 
2019-07-05 16:00:58 CLIENT -> SERVER: .
2019-07-05 16:00:59 SERVER -> CLIENT: 554 5.2.0
```

El error generado es el siguiente:

```
STOREDRV.Submission.Exception:SendAsDeniedException.MapiExceptionSendAsDenied; Failed to process message due to a permanent exception with message Cannot submit message. 16.55847:260F0000, 17.43559:0000000004020000000000000100000000000000, 20.52176:140FF0870800F01FCB030000, 20.50032:140FF0878317401080030400, 0.35180:D0030000, 255.23226:0A00A382, 255.27962:0A000000, 255.27962:0E000000, 255.31418:1F000130, 16.55847:88000000, 17.43559:00000000E0020000000000000200000000000000, 20.52176:140FF087080040108
    2019-07-05 16:00:59 SMTP ERROR: DATA END command failed: 554 5.2.0 STOREDRV.Submission.Exception:SendAsDeniedException.MapiExceptionSendAsDenied; Failed to process message due to a permanent exception with message Cannot submit message. 16.55847:260F0000, 17.43559:0000000004020000000000000100000000000000, 20.52176:140FF0870800F01FCB030000, 20.50032:140FF0878317401080030400, 0.35180:D0030000, 255.23226:0A00A382, 255.27962:0A000000, 255.27962:0E000000, 255.31418:1F000130, 16.55847:88000000, 17.43559:00000000E0020000000000000200000000000000, 20.52176:140FF087080040108
    SMTP Error: data not accepted.
    Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: SMTP Error: data not accepted.SMTP server error: DATA END command failed Detail: STOREDRV.Submission.Exception:SendAsDeniedException.MapiExceptionSendAsDenied; Failed to process message due to a permanent exception with message Cannot submit message. 16.55847:260F0000, 17.43559:0000000004020000000000000100000000000000, 20.52176:140FF0870800F01FCB030000, 20.50032:140FF0878317401080030400, 0.35180:D0030000, 255.23226:0A00A382, 255.27962:0A000000, 255.27962:0E000000, 255.31418:1F000130, 16.55847:88000000, 17.43559:00000000E0020000000000000200000000000000, 20.52176:140FF087080040108 SMTP code: 554 Additional SMTP info: 5.2.02019-07-05 16:00:59 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
```

Es posible que me falte alguna configuración?

El servidor esta activo y funcionando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El servidor de correo no permite tener una Direccion de envio o un usuario diferentes, tienes que poner los mismo, espero te sirva

```
$mail->Username   = 'correo@domio.com'; 
$mail->From= 'correo@domio.com';
```

Comment: muchas gracias, no tenia idea que se tenia q hacer de esa manera.

Comment: @angelcabrales ya te funciona no?

Comment: me funciona el envio de forma local @KeTeMeTo, el problema ahora es con el servidor de GODADDY

Comment: me salvaste. Después de 20 horas era esa la solución....